# Can we use the concept of a railgun or coilgun to design a small particle accelerator?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, acceleration, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

[image: apparent design in my head.]A railgun is used as a linear particle accelerator to project projectile at high speeds. Why not use this concept to build a circular rail particle accelerator. A conventional railgun uses extremely high power to shoot projectile. This would run on lower power as the projectile could go upto several rounds being accelerated on low current and when reached desired velocity can be launched linearly. This would surely take time but one would achieve high velocity at low current. I'm keen to know the catch if there is any. Thanks!

Comment: how do you think the LHC works?

Comment: But doesn't it use enormous power? My point is to use less current to accelerate it several times in circular motion.

Comment: @SarthakTyagi as would a railgun, plus the added cost of repairing the rails each acceleration period. You couldn't accelerate it more than once around with a railgun setup.

Answer (score 1):

Circular particle accelerators exist in many place, the most famous likely being the Large Hadron Collider. The thing is, these are *very big* pieces of equipment, not very small ones. The centripetal acceleration required to keep a particle in a circular path is proportional to the square of the velocity, and inversely proportional to the radius - as the radius shrinks, you need greater acceleration, and as the velocity increases, you need much greater acceleration. You can't run a small-radius particle acceleator on low power, since the smaller radius requires a greater force/acceleration to keep the particle on track.

The LHC uses a great deal of power. Making it smaller would require it to use *even more* power, not less.

Comment: The first cyclotron was less than 12cm in diameter and accelerated protons into the MV range. Small storage rings are pretty simple to build. Just not at the TV particle energy...

Comment: As the radius of a particle under magnetic field is mv/qb. Can't we use external magnetic field to variate the radius of its path?

Comment: If it's radius shrink is inevitable then why not use a rail coil instead of 1 turn we can add several turn until it's end reaches the centre where it's acceleration is maximum and hence release it from there linearly?